# Partial decryption of a message

Tags: encryption

I am working on a banking project. In this project, our customers will POST us sensitive and non-sensitive data about one of their clients, ideally in one package like a ZIP. So even the non-sensitive data must be sent encrypted. However, we - acting as an intermediary - need to be able to read the non-sensitive data.

So I am looking for an encryption/decryption mechanism or product that supports encrypting and entire message and allowing decryption of some part(s) of the message. How could this be achieved? Which encryption algorithm(s) to use?

Comment: Different keys and different zip files?

Comment: Thanks @JonathonReinhart for your suggestion. We had thought of that option, but we would prefer to use a single file/ZIP which contains both types of data, to keep the client onboarding process as simple as possible.

Comment: you can use Searchable Encryption (SE) .